# Is there a way to create a "switch" view that uses a static image instead of the normal off on switch?

Tags: ios, swift

Basically what I want to do is have a "switch" image that has 2 different states. When on, it changes the tint color of the image and when off it changes it back to what it was. I can do this by having 2 Icons in the view (one for on, one for off) and then only showing one of them when needed and hiding the other but is there a better way I can achieve this without having to add 2 images?

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the tint color of the same image:
for one state you can pass your desired color to function below and pass another for another state.
do

```
func updateImage(withColor tintColor:UIColor){
    self.yourImageView.image = yourImageView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    self.yourImageView.tintColor = tintColor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Core Image built-in-Filters. Below is a sample of how you would use it (in case you don't want your multiple buttons there is a tap gesture to switch image states). if you do want a single button you can use the code located in `handleTap`.

Here is a list of filters you could use with the below snippet [Apple Core Image Filters](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/processing_an_image_using_built-in_filters)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    //Connect to your imageView in interface builder
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    
    let originalImage = UIImage(named: "YourImageName")
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageView.image = originalImage
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        //Allows the imageView to register user touches
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    //Filter function
    func sepiaFilter(_ input: CIImage, intensity: Double) -> CIImage? {
        let sepiaFilter = CIFilter(name:"CISepiaTone")
        sepiaFilter?.setValue(input, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        sepiaFilter?.setValue(intensity, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
        return sepiaFilter?.outputImage
    }
    
    //Tap gesture function that switches the image state
    @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if imageView.image == originalImage {
            let originalCIImage = CIImage(image: originalImage!)
            let CIImage = sepiaFilter(originalCIImage!, intensity:0.9)
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(ciImage:CIImage!)
        } else {
            imageView.image = originalImage
        }
    }

}
```